# Submitting value of an input field

Tags: jsp, submit

How can I submit a value defined as

```
<input id="inputProperties" tabindex="23" class="input_enabled" 
       name="inputProperties" size="60" maxlength="80" value="" />
```

using something like

```
<a tabindex="27" class="text_warn" id="executeCR" 
   href="javascript:document.ejbRuleForm.action.value='execute';
     document.Form.conditionalRuleId.value=<c:out value='${param.entryId}'/>;
     document.Form.inputProperties.value=<c:out value='${inputProperties}' />;
     document.Form.executeChildRules.value=<c:out value='${executeChildRules}' />;
     document.Form.submit();" >
```

Comment: Uhm...where exactly is the question in that? Please consider adding more details about what exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are asking.

If that `<input>` is inside the `<form>` you're submitting, it will effectively get submitted with the parameter name of the `name` attribute of the `input`.

In case the `<input>` is not in the `<form>`, you might want to include for instance a `<input type="hidden">` inside the form and assign the `<input>`'s value to the hidden before form submission.